# Workflow initiated by difference in Modified and Current dates - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Good Morning,

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2007 to create a workflow for a MOSS site I have created.

What I'm looking to do is have the workflow send out an email if a document in the library hasn't been modified for the past 30 days (and it's Status field is not set as "Closed"), but I'm stumped as to how I can do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the "Pause for duration" action (under "Core Actions" when you are adding an action to your SPD workflow).

*However*, I've worked on something that had a similar requirement and we decided that workflow was not the best option. We have a console application that is scheduled to run everyday and queries the list for "old" items. If it finds any old items, then it sends out an email to the user.

Comment: +1 for the second option. A console app or timer job is a better solution for this.